# Correlation between two strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, match, correlation

I am trying to find if there is a relationship between two columns in a dataset.  I am using fuzzywuzzy and the partial_ratio to identify if there is a "match" between a keyword column, and an "issue title" column.

Key keyword column is full of meta data tags for articles with a space separator. My code works fine, but i am wondering if there is a better way to do what i am trying to do?

CODE:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz   

df.dropna(subset=['Keywords', 'Issue'], inplace=True)
df['Acc'] = df.apply(lambda rows: fuzz.partial_ratio(rows['Keywords'],rows['Issue']),axis = 1)
df[['Issue','Keywords','Len','Acc']].head(1)
```

This returns the following dataframe:

```
| Issue | Keywords                                                                                            | Len | Acc |
|-------|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|-----|-----|
| 0     | General information regarding proof of employm... Verification Employment calls Work Number VOE ... | 19  | 57  |
```

So, there are 19 keywords in the Len column, and 57 on a match score.  Cool, so, is there any other way to identify if the correct "tags" are being used and are 100% related to the "issue" column?

Comment: Maybe you filter out stop words before matching. I am assuming `fuzzywuzzy` does not do this internally and bases the score on these words too, which may not be necessary.

Comment: @Vivek Kumar, I was thinking about doing that as well, great advice my friend.  Thank you.  Filter out stop words from both columns, and then check the match.  Now the only reason why i didn't do that in the beginning, is because I need to create a "quality report" that shows the quality of the existing tags/keywords.  I am wondering if i create a report saying "here is how many stop words you have" and if you remove them this is what the quality could look like?... hmmm...